# Get JSON's attribute value in Chatterbot and Django integration

Tags: json, django, chatterbot

statement.text in chatterbot and Django integration returns

```
{'text': u'How are you doing?', 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 20, 7, 37, 30, 746345, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'extra_data': {}, 'in_response_to': [{'text': u'Hi', 'occurrence': 3}]}
```

I want a value of text attribute so that it prints How are you doing?

Comment: Is that actual dict ? If not can convert to dict using `json.loads(data)` ?

Comment: could you try latest chatterbot==0.6.1? to resolve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `chatterbot` return the `json` object`(dict`) so you can use the `dictionary` operations like following

```
[1]: data = {'text': u'How are you doing?', 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 20, 7, 37, 30, 746345, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'extra_data': {}, 'in_response_to': [{'text': u'Hi', 'occurrence': 3}]}

[2]: data['text'] or data.get('text')[this approch is good].
```

Comment: wht you getting from chatterbot

Answer (score 1):

What you got is dictionary. Value of dictionary can be obtained by get() function. You can also use dict['text'], but it does not perform error checking. get function returns None if key is not present.